# Why is my float being truncated?

Tags: java, floating-point, ieee-754

Entering a value such as `27.8675309` into the "Decimal representation" field of the [IEEE 754 Converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatApplet/IEEE754.html) changes the value I entered to `27.86753`.  Likewise, Java drops the last two digits when a parse a string with the same value.

```
Float.parseFloat("27.8675309") // Results in a float value of 27.86753
```

I am not sure what the "Decimal representation" of the IEEE converter actually is (is it a float?) but I would expect it to give me the biggest number possible that:

1. Is a float value
2. Does not exceed the original value I entered

I would expect Java to behave in a similar fashion, that is, I would expect the line of code above to return a float value equal to `27.8675308` or an even larger float value that is closer to my original input instead of just dropping decimal places.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Perhaps `double` is a better choice than `float` if you need more precision.

Comment: @typoknig Is the "8675309" a coincidence or from that hit 80's song?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is as expected.

If you look at the binary representation of 27.8675309 (27.867530822753906 as a double):

```
01000001110111101111000010110100
```

the next highest value is:

```
01000001110111101111000010110101
```

which yields 27.867533 (27.86753273010254 as a double), and the next lowest value is:

```
01000001110111101111000010110011
```

which yields 27.867529 (27.867528915405273 as a double)

There simply aren't enough bits in the mantissa of a `Float` to represent any value in between, so your value is rounded down in decimal to 27.867530

Comment: The first two binary numbers are identical, but I think I see what you are saying.

Comment: Also, just so I am clear, this isn't a matter of running out of decimal places, it is a matter of no more bits for the exponent and/or mantissa of the float, correct?  Some other float value could have more than 5 decimal places right?

Comment: @typoknig it's not more bits for the mantissa - this number is small enough that the exponent doesn't matter.  And yes, smaller numbers could have more than five decimal places, but no more than 7 or 8 significant digits.

Comment: @Alnitak 27.8675309 rounded to 24 bits = 11011.11011110000101101 = 27.86753082275390625. Rounded to 8 decimal digits, that's 27.867531, not 27.867530. To 7 digits, it's 27.86753, but then so are both the prev float (27.8675289154052734375) and the next float (27.8675327301025390625). Why is http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatApplet/IEEE754.html rounding 27.8675309 to 7 digits, but prev and next to 8?

Comment: @RickRegan in IEE754 the 27 won't be part of the mantissa - you'll actually have 2^4 * 1.741720...

Comment: @Alnitak But the value it represents is 1.741720676422119140625 * 2^4 = 27.86753082275390625

Comment: The answer is: The converter uses Java, which rounds a floating-point value to the shortest decimal representation that converts back to the same floating-point value. (Thanks to Harald Schmidt for pointing this out.)

Answer (score 1):

As Alnitak mentioned, you've run out of bits. You could use `Double` for higher precision, though. `Double` implements 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point whereas `Float` implements 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point.