# Auto truncation of float value

Tags: java

Need help with the following. I following value is getting truncated as follows:

```
    float data1 = 48.12345678f;
    float data2 = 12.12345678f;
    float data3 = 90.12345678f;
    float data4 = 56.12345678f;

    System.out.println(data1);
    System.out.println(data2);
    System.out.println(data3);
    System.out.println(data4);

Output -

48.123455
12.123457
90.12346
56.123455
```

It looks like a float value property and it will get fixed if we use double value.

This is varying across different system even though the JVM version seems same. So I need to find an explanation on what basis the rounding off is taking place. In one instance it is incrementing the digit (12.123457) and in one decrementing (48.123455). So could you please help me understand the reason of this ambiguity and what property is varying the result from different system.

Comment: It is beacuse of loss of precision on storing such precise values in a float-variable!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my float being truncated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083905/why-is-my-float-being-truncated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to how float numbers are represented in the computer memory. Here's an online demo of how float numbers are stored in memory (binary representation)

http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

According to the IEEE 754 standard, a single precision number is stored in a 32bit word composed of one sign bit, 8 exponents bits, and 23 mantissa bits. If you follow the steps of how to represent the number `48.12345678` you will find that there's underflow and some bits are truncated because it exceeds the 23 mantissa bits

Example, in the above link, try to plug: 48.12345678 in the Decimal Representation, then press enter. You will see that the number will be converted to `48.123455` and above it you will find the single precision representation of the number in binary

Answer (score 1):

To start with your questions,the rounding off is obviously system-specific as the CPU represents floating point data as per it's own way.

So in your case---> In one instance it is incrementing the digit (12.123457) and in one decrementing (48.123455).It is happening on different machines or systems.

As the numbers are stored in the system in binaries,SO `The binary representation of the numbers may not be exact.`

> It is not unusual for specific floating point or double precision
>   numbers to not be represented exactly as desired. Floating-point
>   decimal values generally do not have an exact binary representation
>   due to how the CPU represents floating point data. For this reason,
>   you may experience a loss of precision, and some floating-point
>   operations may produce unexpected results